# Given $n$ sets of matrices, find $n$ matrices that have the least number of LCDs among their entries

Tags: algorithms, matrices, integers, factoring

Let's say I have $n$ sets of matrices

$$
A = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 & 17\\
5 & 6 & 9\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 & 18\\
5 & 6 & 9\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$

$$
B = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
13 & 20\\
3 & 16\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
14 & 20\\
3 & 16\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
13 & 21\\
3 & 16\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
14 & 21\\
3 & 16\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
13 & 20\\
3 & 17\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
14 & 20\\
3 & 17\\
\end{pmatrix}
...
\right\}
$$

Let's define $T$ as a vector that contains the lowest common denominators shared among the entries of $n$ matrices, picking one per set.

I need to find $n$ matrices that will minimize the length of $T$, i.e. in this case

$$
A_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4 & 18\\
5 & 6 & 9\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
B_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
14 & 20\\
3 & 16\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The resulting $T$ would be

$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
2,3,5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here is the computation of $T$ given the matrices, entry by entry:

- Sort all the terms in a vector $[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 14, 16, 18, 20]$
- For each sorted term, find a divider. If it exists, remove the current term and continue to the next iteration.

I know I can bruteforce every possible combination, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Why would $T$ be a vector?  The gcd of a bunch of numbers is a single integer.  I suspect I am not understanding.  Can you state the definition of $T$ more clearly?

Comment: I actually made a mistake in exposing the example value for $T$, see the update

Comment: To explain this further: the terms $4, 6, 14, 16, 18, 20$ are all divisible by $2$ (which is among the matrices' entries), so they go away; the term $9$ is divisible by $3$, so it goes away!

Comment: In ur example this happens because 2&3 r elements in one of the matrices in the set in hand so they appeared in the T vector, right? or am I getting it wrong & u r searching for the set that contains the min no of primes?

Comment: I'm so confused by the problem statement.  I still don't understand what is meant by "the lowest common denominators shared among the entries of n matrices, picking one per set".  It seems like that tries to pack too much into one sentence.  Can you give a more detailed specification of $T$?  Maybe you need to break it down into multiple definitions; maybe you can use mathematics.  Examples are not a substitute for a clear problem statement.  I don't want to have to guess, or to have to reverse-engineer the problem from the examples.

Comment: I don't know what "find a divider" means.  It seems like your computation of $T$ is nondeterministic (if you run it twice on the same inputs, you might get two different outputs), so it doesn't seem like a definition of $T$.

Comment: Perhaps the goal is to find the smallest set $T \subseteq \{2,3,4,\dots,\}$ and to choose one matrix from each set, so that every element in each chosen matrix is divisible by at least number in $T$?  Is that correct?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task?  Did you see it in a book, a contest, something like that?  Can you cite the original source?  Or can you share the motivation?

Comment: Definitely a set, not a vector! I got this problem in a coding challenge, couldn't pull it off. They said there's an efficient solution.